# JavaScript: else if won't work in for loops [Spreadsheet]

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to loop through the whole row in my google sheet and break it at the last row +1
'i' as an indicator for stopping the loop, using else-if condition.
But somehow the loop won't go through else-if condition.

- The loop stops when 'i' doesn't meet the for-loop condition, How can I make it stop when meeting else-if condition instead ?

I'm fresh and new to Javascript and Appscript, will grateful for every advise.

```
function makedict(){
  var product = {}
  var code = code_dicted
  var name = name_dicted
  var unit = unit_dicted
  var balance = balance_dicted


  var value0 = sheet.getRange("C:M").getValues().map(row => [ row[0]]); //code
  var value1 = sheet.getRange("C:M").getValues().map(row => [ row[1]]); //name
  var value5 = sheet.getRange("C:M").getValues().map(row => [ row[5]]); //bal
  var value6 = sheet.getRange("C:M").getValues().map(row => [ row[10]]); //unit
  var range = sheet.getRange("C:M").getValues().length
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  var dict = {}
  var result = "\n\n\n"


for (i = 1;i < range;i++){
  

  dict["code"] = value0[i]
  var code_dicted = dict["code"]
  var code = code_dicted


  dict["name"] = value1[i]
  var name_dicted = dict["name"]
  var name = name_dicted

  dict["balance"] = value5[i]
  var balance_dicted = dict["balance"]
  var balance = balance_dicted

  dict["unit"] = value6[i]
  var unit_dicted = dict["unit"]
  var unit = unit_dicted


  product["detail"] = {code,name,balance,unit}
  // console.log(product)
  
  if (product.detail["balance"]<product.detail["unit"]){
    
    var text = product.detail["code"]+product.detail["name"]+product.detail["balance"]+product.detail["unit"];
    result = result.concat(text)+"\n\n"

  }


  else if (i === lastRow+1){
  console.log(result)
  break
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can try increasing your "range" in your for-loop?

Comment: in this case I would go with a while loop

Comment: @BernhardMiehl Thanks ! I've tried using While-loop and it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

Thank you. I've solved it following the above advise.
using While-loop instead.

```
  var i = 1;

  while (i < range){
  

  dict["code"] = value0[i]
  var code_dicted = dict["code"]
  var code = code_dicted


  dict["name"] = value1[i]
  var name_dicted = dict["name"]
  var name = name_dicted

  dict["balance"] = value5[i]
  var balance_dicted = dict["balance"]
  var balance = balance_dicted

  dict["unit"] = value6[i]
  var unit_dicted = dict["unit"]
  var unit = unit_dicted
  i = i+1

  product["detail"] = {code,name,balance,unit}
  // console.log(product)
  
  if (product.detail["balance"]<product.detail["unit"]){
    
    var text = product.detail["code"]+product.detail["name"]+product.detail["balance"]+product.detail["unit"];
    result = result.concat(text)+"\n\n"

  }


  else if (i === lastRow+1){
  console.log(result)
  break
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 1;i < range + 1 ;i++){
```

Try the above code, I'm assuming lastRow is a number and it ranges from `0 to range`